# Как преобразовать файл в массив байтов и отправить по Json

Tags: android, json, kotlin, bytearray

Есть код на C#, который считывает байты в файле, создает объект класса и сериализует его в Json. И выглядит это примерно вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на котлине это выглядит вообще иначе. Как-то так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне сделать такой же Json но на котлине? То есть мне нужно считать байты с файла и создать Json вида content: byte[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, Вам необходим Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString()

```
    val bytes = File(filePath).readBytes()
    val base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes)
```

https://bezkoder.com/kotlin-base64/

Кодируете массив байт в base64 и вставляете в content объекта json, а на другой стороне декодируете

Answer (score 0):

Возможно этот метод для преобразования строки в байты вам подойдет:

```
val charset = Charsets.UTF_8
val byteArray = "A B C D".toByteArray(charset)
println(byteArray.contentToString()) // [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
println(byteArray.toString(charset)) // Hello
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html

Про работу с файлами:

Чтение
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-bytes.html

Запись https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/write-bytes.html